# ArcGIS - viewshed calculation using a DSM and DEM

Tags: arcgis-desktop, viewshed

I am fairly new at using ArcGIS.  For work we use it only to create viewshed analysis using DEM - or bare earth terrain.

I can create these fine, however I need to create one showing the effects of vegetation and buildings. I have received a DSM of the site, but if I take it through the normal process, as we do for the bare earth, it calculates the DSM surface, rather than calculating the view from the terrain.

So for example, where there are clearly trees and buildings, it shows that you can in fact see the observation point, even though you know you wouldn't because of the tree and buildings would be covering it.

I can't seem to find any step by step tutorials that can help me out,  I'm sorry for my lack of detail and wording on explaining my problem. 
I am really really new to this, and have been thrown in the deep end by work wanting me to find the answer!

Comment: It could be that the default offset is nullifying the canopy and building heights. Here is the online help that describes the model concepts and parameters (http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000v8000000.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Start here.
You will need to burn your building and canopy into your surface.
You will need to decide how to depict your canopy.

[ESRI resources help.](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000v3000000).
And this thread from one of our own [esri forum](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=995&t=271212).
Another [forum post asking for the same help](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/87271-Partial-building-viewshed) you are.
This is still a step closer.  [ESRI blog](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2011/09/29/2d-to-3d/) but the template is still empty.
It looks like ESRI. Is ramping this up.
Here is [video](http://video.esri.com/watch/915/how-to-turn-your-2d-features-into-3d-and-have-them-sit-nicely-on-a-surface) to possibly show what you need.